# geocoding 6000+ addresses using pygeocoder (not working because it limited the queries to be used)

Tags: python, geocoding

I'm using pygeocoder in Python in order to extract the longitude and latitude of a number of addresses, but the error came in, saying that the query was over the limit. Does anybody know any other open source tools to geocode this many records one at a time? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

*pygeocoder* uses the *Google Geocoding API* which imposes [usage limits](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/#Limits).

Assuming you a using the free API your limits are:

> - 2,500 requests per 24 hour period.
> - 10 requests per second.

Consequently you could just spread out your request across three days without changing your code.

If you *really* need to geocode a large number of addresses at once you probably have to resort to a paid service.